# mysql Compress() with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

*table*:
**id**(integer primary key)
**data**(blob)

I use mysql and sqlalchemy.
To insert data I use:

```
o = Demo()
o.data = mydata
session.add(o)
session.commit()
```

I would like to insert to table like that:

```
INSERT INTO table(data) VALUES(COMPRESS(mydata))
```

How can I do this using sqlalchemy?

Comment: `object = object()` seems not a good idea to me. You are overwriting the type name `object`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign a SQL function to the attribute:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
object.data = func.compress(mydata)
session.add(object)
session.commit()
```

Here's an example using a more DB-agnostic lower() function:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base= declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String)

e = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)
s = Session(e)

a1 = A()
a1.data = func.lower("SomeData")
s.add(a1)
s.commit()

assert a1.data == "somedata"
```

you can make it automatic with @validates:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates
class MyClass(Base):
    # ...
    data = Column(BLOB)

    @validates("data")
    def _set_data(self, key, value):
        return func.compress(value)
```

if you want it readable in python before the flush, you'd need to memoize it locally and use a descriptor to access it.