# SELECT UNCOMPRESS(text) FROM with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I store the MySQL Compress function to insert compressed blob data to the database.

In a previous question I was instructed to to use

```
func.compress
```

( [mysql Compress() with sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894706/mysql-compress-with-sqlalchemy) )

The problem now is that I want to read also the data from the database.
In mysql I would have done

```
SELECT UNCOMPRESS(text) FROM ...
```

probably I should use a getter in the class.
I tried to do somethin like:

```
get_html(self):
    return func.uncompress(self.text)
```

but this does not work. It returns an sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Function and not the string.

Moreover I could not find which functions contains sqlalchemy's func.

Any ideas on how i could write a getter in the object so I get back the uncompressed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func` is actually a really fancy factory object for special function objects which are rendered to SQL at query time - you cannot evaluate them in Python since Python would not know how your database implements `compress()`. That's why it doesn't work.

SQLAlchemy lets you map [SQL expressions to mapped class attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property). If you're using the declarative syntax, extend your class like so (it's untested, but I'm confident this is the way to go):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

class Demo(...):
    data_uncompressed = column_property(func.uncompress(data))
```

Now whenever SQLAlchemy loads an instance from the database, the SELECT query will contain `SELECT ..., UNCOMPRESS(demotable.data), ... FROM demotable`.

Edit by Giorgos Komninos:
I used the

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html#using-a-plain-descriptor

and it worked.

Comment: Up-to-date link to the documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property