# sqlAlchemy to access blob via a hybrid propery?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add a block of text into a sqlAlchemy table, which I want to compress to save space with it. Looking through various answers I came up with what I think should be working, but is not. I'm working with a sqlite database.

Updated: Was pointed out I was attempting to use mysql on sqlite which I wasn't aware that was what was happening. I adjusted to use zlib instead and it works to a degree, which gives me a new error that I do not understand.

```
# proper imports and stuff to make this work
from sqlalchemy import func

class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data'

    # ...

    text_blobbed = Column('text', BLOB)

    @hybrid_property
    def text(self):
        # return func.decompress(self.text_blobbed)
        return self.text_blobbed.decode("zlib")

    @text.setter
    def text(self, stuff):
        # self.text_blobbed = func.compress(stuff)
        self.text_blobbed = stuff.encode("zlib")
```

old error from func.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: compress [SQL: ...... ]
```

I can now add in the text via Data.text = "a really big block of text"

But when I go to query for this like

```
session.query(Data.text).filter(Data.id.like(2)).first()
```

I get an error:
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Data.text_blobbed has an attribute 'decode'

Doing this is fine.

```
r = session.query(Data).filter(Data.id.like(2)).first()
print r.text
```

I've also looked at the text_blobbed which is a set(). And I can do this that works:

```
r = session.query(Data.text_blobbed.filter( ... ).first()[0].decode("zlib")
print r
```

But if I move that [0] into the hybrid_property for

```
...
return self.text_blobbed[0].decode("zlib")
```

and query:

```
r = session.query(Data.text).filter( ... ).first()
```

I get the error:
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression

So, I'm a bit confused still.

I've been looking at these things:

[SQLAlchemy - Writing a hybrid method for child count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640298/sqlalchemy-writing-a-hybrid-method-for-child-count)

[mysql Compress() with sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894706/mysql-compress-with-sqlalchemy)

[SELECT UNCOMPRESS(text) FROM with sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411681/select-uncompresstext-from-with-sqlalchemy?noredirect=1&lq=1)

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html?highlight=descriptor

Comment: [`COMPRESS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) and [`UNCOMPRESS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_uncompress) would seem to be MySQL functions. You seem to be using SQLite.

Comment: If you're set on using SQLite, you could use [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) for compression and decompression Python side. In that case you probably want a [type decorator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html).

Comment: @IljaEverilä With your first comment, I didn't realize that I was looking at mysql only options. That sent me down looking at zlib encode/decode, which gets me the data into the sqlite db. And yes, it needs to be a sqlite since I'm not running any kind of mysql server or backend and this is basically a test. 
Unfortunately doing a query directly for Data.text fails with an AttributeError Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Data.text_blobbed has an attribute 'decode' But it's closer. 
Doing a query just on Data and then going to Data.text works.